# Field Validation and Highlighting

Tags: 7, forms

How can I get custom Form API validation to highlight a field the same way the failed #required validation does?  (See attached graphic)

Note Graphic:

1) (Green Line) Company Name is empty.  '#required' Error is noted and field is highlighted red.

2) (Blue Line) Website is incorrect.  'Custom Validation' Error is noted, but field is NOT highlighted.

How can I automatically highlight the 'Website' field on validation fail and remove it upon success?

Currently using: `form_set_error('', t('Your website address is incorrectly formatted.'));`

See
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [hook_field_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_validate/7)? (edit) I just realized you are not using the new [Field API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/group/field/7) but instead just the Form API. Perhaps, you can build it as a field? If you are familiar with the Form API in d6, you can pick up the Field API in a couple of hours. The Field API is another level of badassness.

i have a custom field that records business hours. I have it set that if a to day is selected there must be a from day. I more or less just implemented the example giving in api.drupal.org.

```
*  Implementation of hook_field_validate()
*/
function hours_field_validate($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, &$errors) {
  foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
    if ($item['end_day'] != '--' && $item['start_day'] == '--') {
      $errors[$field['field_name']][$langcode][$delta][] = array( 
        'error' => t('A from day needs to be choosen if a to day is selected. If they are the same -- forexample, Monday and Monday, the whole line when viewed will only be for Monday.'),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is going at the problem in quite a roundabout way. The Form API has standard ways of highlighting a field that failed validation.

Answer (score 3):

As the first parameter to `form_set_error()`, pass the name of the field to be highlighted. If it's a nested structure, pass it with square brackets, like so:

```
form_set_error('[your][nested][field]', 'Your Error Message');
```

There's a convenience wrapper around this, [`form_error`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_error/7), which takes the element instead of the string, like so:

```
form_error($form['your_field'], 'Your Error Message');
```

Also see the [docs to `form_set_error()` (d7)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7).

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestions did not work for me.  Neither form_error or form_set_error worked in highlighting the error field.  I do get the error message, though.  I am using hook_node_view and drupal_get_form to add a form to a node.  Maybe this is why?  Oh well

Comment: @user785179 - this must be some unrelated problem. It sounds like the FAPI element you mean to work with is not there, or is incomplete, or whatever. I recommend setting a breakpoint on the call to form(_set)_error and examine the variables. Note that `form_error` really only wraps `form_set_error`, all the former does is figure out the first parameter to the latter from the FAPI array.

Answer (score 2):

If your form element is defined like that:

```
$form['panes']['webform_nid31'][0]['contact_person'] = array( ... );
```

your form_set_error call should look like that:

```
form_set_error('panes][webform_nid31][0][contact_person',
                t('You must select a name for this group of settings.'));
```

You need to set full path to element, without outside `[` and `]`. You could have many "contact_person" fields in one form, just in different branches of a form tree. Using only last index would made setting errors ambiguous, thus it's not supported. At least officially. Might work, but only as an undocumented feature.

Formatting this string is [described in API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7):

> Parameters
>
> $name: The name of the form element. If the #parents property of your form element is array('foo', 'bar', 'baz') then you may set an error on 'foo' or 'foo][bar][baz'. Setting an error on 'foo' sets an error for every element where the #parents array starts with 'foo'.

*Copied from [form_set_error() field not highlited red](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78471/form-set-error-field-not-highlited-red)*