# form_set_error() field not highlited red

Tags: 7, forms

When validating a field manually from my form a error is displayed but the field doesn't get red. For the first parameter i used the name of the input element. DRUPAL 7

```
if($form_state['values']['panes']['webform_nid31'][0]['contact_person'] == '') {
    form_set_error('panes[webform_nid31][0][contact_person]', t('You must select a name for this group of settings.'));
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your form element is defined like that:

```
$form['panes']['webform_nid31'][0]['contact_person'] = array( ... );
```

your form_set_error call should look like that:

```
form_set_error('panes][webform_nid31][0][contact_person',
                t('You must select a name for this group of settings.'));
```

You need to set full path to element, without outside `[` and `]`. You could have many "contact_person" fields in one form, just in different branches of a form tree. Using only last index would made setting errors ambiguous, thus it's not supported. At least officially. Might work, but only as an undocumented feature.

Formatting this string is [described in API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7):

> Parameters
>
> $name: The name of the form element. If the #parents property of your form element is array('foo', 'bar', 'baz') then you may set an error on 'foo' or 'foo][bar][baz'. Setting an error on 'foo' sets an error for every element where the #parents array starts with 'foo'.

Last but not least, actual output is defined in theme, it might well be something other than red border if theme author decided so.

Comment: You can infer the form structure from the values array in the question: `$form_state['values']['panes']['webform_nid31'][0]['contact_person']` == `$form['panes']['webform_nid31'][0]['contact_person']`. On another note, have you seen any official reference for this? I only know to do this because I was told about it by another developer a few years back, I haven't ever seen it written down

Comment: @Clive In theory I know that, simply after 9 hours of working at one particularly irritating form, first day on heart drugs, my mind isn't as bright as it should be. Sorry again.

Comment: you solution works but it should also work by giving the name of the element as first parameter. As you are saying this should give all elements with that name a red border. But even though that might nog be what I want as an end result it should work.

Comment: @Clive official reference added

Comment: @Mołot Guess I didn't look too hard ;)

Comment: @Frogger Sorry, corrected